# How do i group values into a list from a group of values with repeating values in python

Tags: python, list

i have values derived from a block of code that extracts those values from aws s3. The code which extacts these values is this.

```
for my_bucket_files in bucket_name.objects.all():
    split_objects = my_bucket_files.key.split('/')
    single_split_objects = split_objects[0]
    print(single_split_objects)
```

This prints out a values in a format like this:

```
air squat 
air squat
air squat
air squat
push up
push up 
push up
push up
lunges 
lunges
lunges
bench press
bench press
bench press
```

I wanna group these values such that i get a list of values that come back in a format
whether be it a list as long as i can utilise it later on.

```
air squat
push up
lunges
bench press
```

How do i go about doing this.

Comment: can you provide example input? look into sets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean that you want a unique list

```
collection = set()
for my_bucket_files in bucket_name.objects.all():
    split_objects = my_bucket_files.key.split('/')
    single_split_objects = split_objects[0]
    collection.add(single_split_objects)
uniq = list(collection)
```

`collection` is a set. Sets contain unique elements only so the `add` function will only add an element if it is not already contained within the set.

Because sets are iterable, `list(collection)` will convert the set to a list.

Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: Thank you so much, this basically worked like a charm. I'm really grateful. I'm still a beginner in python so i have a long way to go. THANK YOU.....

Answer (score 2):

Use a set comprehension, like this:

```
unique_values = {b.key.split("/")[0] for b in bucket_name.objects.all()}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
lst=[]
for my_bucket_files in bucket_name.objects.all():
    split_objects = my_bucket_files.key.split('/')
    single_split_objects = split_objects[0]
    if single_split_objects not in lst:
        lst.append(single_split_objects)
print(lst)
['air squat','push up','lunges','bench press']
```